# Compare two files, if the columns are same then replace next column with some value

Tags: linux, scripting, csv

How do I replace a column value in a file when compared with another file?

I have two files *test1.csv* and *test2.csv*; I need to replace the `empdep` column in *test1.csv* if it has the value as *"sign*"*.  The second file *test2.csv* has the value needed to replace that *"sign*"*.

Note : I'm using `ksh` and *test1.csv* has around 2,048,576 rows and *test2.csv* has 10000 rows.

test1.csv

```
empname,place,empdep
aaaa,city1,001
bbbb,city2,sign-1
dddd,city1,005
ffff,city5,sign-2
hhhh,city7,sign-1
```

test2.csv

```
empname,new
aaaa,001
bbbb,002
cccc,003
dddd,005
eeee,006
ffff,007
gggg,008
hhhh,009
```

Expected result:

```
empname,place,empdep
aaaa,city1,001
bbbb,city2,002
dddd,city1,005
ffff,city5,007
hhhh,city7,009
```

Comment: @agc I incorporated the space characters of the original images intentionally (output was consistent), but thanks for the fix!

Comment: @Quasímodo I had considered that, but for a code-free novice Q. the spaces are irrelevant to the problem.  It's highly probable those spaces were typos, because the OP's first draft was full of them.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } # set input/output field separator to `,`
  NR==FNR{            # if this is the first file `test2.csv`
    a[$1]=$2          # store field2 in array `a` using field1 as index
    next              # continue with next line
  } 
  $3 ~ /^sign/{       # if field3 of `test1.csv` begins with `sign`
    $3=a[$1]          # replace the field with array value (index of field1)
  }
  1                   # print the line
' test2.csv test1.csv
```

Comment: Hi Freddy, Thanks for your quick response... But i have question here... where we are checking/comparing the employename of table1 and table2 are equal or not?

for example.... column 2 in table 1 is sign, then it should compare the empname in both the table, then it should replace the deptname. 

where the above condition is getting check?

Comment: instead of $3, i tried the above code for $7( just changed $3 into $7 in code) but got empty space istead of value... Please check below

xfsgdh|gdjshd|bbbb|20191228|230||sign-1|14420|44766|||||||20191228 --- original
xfsgdh|gdjshd|bbb|20191228|230|||14420|44766|||||||20191228 - result after code

Comment: We check if column3 in `test1.csv` starts with `sign`, we don't check if `empname` exists in the array, we assume it is. Example: row3 contains `bbbb,city2,sign-1` and array `a` contains an entry `a[bbbb]=002` and we replace field3 with `$3=a[$1]`
where `$1` is the value `bbbb` of row3.

Comment: If you're using the separator `|`, then change the `","` to `"|"`.

Comment: so, i understood here is, for this indexing method the file1 and file2 should have same number of rows.. correct me if i'm wrong... Reason for this question is, i got empty space instead of replaced value.

Please check below 

xfsgdh|gdjshd|bbbb|20191228|230||sign-1|14420|44766|||||||20191228 --- original xfsgdh|gdjshd|bbb|20191228|230|||14420|44766|||||||20191228 - result after code 

in my file1 i almost 100000 rows, but in file2 i have 1000 rows only...

Comment: actually i did change "," to "|" as below

awk '
  BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
  NR==FNR{            
    a[$1]=$2          
    next              
  } 
  $7 ~ /^sign{       
    $7=a[$1]          
  }
  1                  
' file2.csv file1.csv > file3.csv

Comment: The code would be `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $7~/^sign/{$7=a[$1]}1' file2 file1 > file3` and the array is associative, you only need the values in the mapping in the second file for the values where field7 begins with `sign`.
Do you have `|` as separator in `file2`? Is it really the first column in `file1` that contains `empname`? You have a `bbbb` in your previous comment which would be `$7=a[$3]`.

Comment: When try print its displaying as below. so as per your command which one will be taking?

awk -F\| '{print $1}' file2.csv
empname
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
ffff
gggg
hhhh

awk '{print $1}' file2.csv
empname,new
aaaa|001
bbbb|002
cccc|003
dddd|005
eeee|006
ffff|007
gggg|008
hhhh|009

Comment: when i print $2 without "|" field separator, it is showing null(empty space), i guess this is what giving empty space in output instead of value. can you please suggest on this?

Comment: Well, you should know what your field separator is. Is it a `|` or a space or a comma? I don't have your data and you only showed your sample data in the question which seems to be different (number of columns, separator).

Comment: Apologies for back back questions...

i have both comma separator and pipe separator files... so i tried in pipe separator(both file1 and file 2 are pipe separator only). above command which u given is working but instead of replace the data it giving empty space... That's why it checked for $2 to know whether it is giving space or value to the index. if try without field separator, it is giving space only to index, with field separator it is giving value.

as the command which u given having field separator "|" then also why it is giving space to the output?

Comment: In the first step for `file2` in `a[$1]=$2` we're using field1 as array index and field2 as value (holding the new value for `empdep`). Field1 has to match the `empname` field of file1 (probably `$1`). I don't know if you have corresponding values in both files.

Answer (score 0):

This is one simple way :

```
for i in $(cat text1.csv)  
do  
    name=$(echo $i | cut -d',' -f1)   
    empdep=$(echo $i | cut -d',' -f3)  
    newvalue=$(grep $name text2.csv | cut -d',' -f2)    
    if [[ $empdep = sign* ]]    
    then  
        sed -n "s/^$name,\(.*\),.*/$name,\1,$newvalue/pg" text1.csv  
    else  
        echo $i  
    fi  
done
```

Comment: Yeah i agree ... it will be slow...

Comment: That way is not *"simple"*.  Instead of `for` and `cat`, consider using `while IFS=, read name f2 emdep f4`, and `done < text1.csv`, that way lines #3-#4 aren't needed.  Consider using an associative array instead of the `grep` and `sed` stuff.

Comment: I meant simple to be understandable by beginner...obviously you are right . But sometimes while loop unable to get the sub shell's value of a variable ...so i used for loop...

Answer (score 0):

Using `ksh` and `sed`.  Use `sed` to parse *test2.csv* and populate an [associative array](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch06_04.htm#IXT-6-287836) `${new[@]}`.  Then loop through *test1.csv* and use [pattern substitution](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch04_05.htm#korn2-IDXTERM-931) to print the desired outputs:

```
typeset -A new $(sed -n '2,${s/^/new[/;s/,/]=/p}' test2.csv)
while IFS=, read a b c; do echo $a,$b,${c/#sign*/${new[$a]}}; done < test1.csv
```

Output:

```
empname,place,empdep
aaaa,city1,001
bbbb,city2,002
dddd,city1,005
ffff,city5,007
hhhh,city7,009
```

---

Note:  In this instance the input files have no quotes, and the code is visually simpler without quotes.    If either input file contains, (or might contain), spaces, the variables above **must** be quoted.

Comment: The `$b` isn't strictly needed.  This `while IFS=, read a c; do echo $a,${c/,sign*/,${new[$a]}}; done < test1.csv` would also work...

Answer (score 0):

```
csv-merge -N t1 -p test1.csv -N t2 -p test2.csv | 
csv-sqlite -T 'select t1.empname, t1.place, case when t1.empdep like "sign%" then t2.new else t1.empdep end as empdep
from t1 left join t2 on t1.empname = t2.empname'
```

csv-merge and csv-sqlite are from https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools